# append the new parameter to the same the current url parameter in get form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have an url with parameter such as

```
http://localhost:8000/search_doctor_home?specialty_id=1
```

and I have a get form and I need the new parameter to the current parameters
so it is going to be

```
http://localhost:8000/search_doctor_home?specialty_id=1&degree_srch=4
```

not

```
http://localhost:8000/search_doctor_home?degree_srch=4
```

and I tried the following methods but it does not work

```
   <form method="GET" action="{{ url()->full() }}">
```

and

```
  <form method="GET" action="{{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['degree_srch' => 4]) }}">
```

Comment: have you tried the `fullUrlWithQuery` method of Request? `request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['degree_srch' => 4])`?

Comment: @lagbox yes, i have tried it, but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current query array by `request()->query()`, and merge the new params with the query array and appends to the url:

```
request()->fullUrlWithQuery(array_merge(request()->query(), ['degree_srch' => 4]));
```

or

```
route('your_route_name', array_merge(request()->query(), ['degree_srch' => 4]));
```